# Reading Package list takes too long in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, command-line, apt

When I enter `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt-get install somthing` in ubuntu 14.04 server *Reading Package List* takes too long time. When I changed name of */etc/apt/sources.list* doesn't take too long, but I can't install what I want. please help me.

Comment: How long is too long?

Comment: @wjandrea 30 to 45 minutes just for sudo apt-get update